# Securing sent POST data to another server (with redirect)

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am doing SMS payments.

I have to redirect my user to another site (to that payment site) with some POST variables.
So I created form with hidden fields, where some infos are.. Including price!
So then visitor click on button, he will be redirected to payment site and etc..
But, they can change the input hidden fields, submit form and pay lower price. (I hope, you understand)

I was thinking about cURL, but I need to redirect user. (I dont know how to do it with cURL).

Is there any solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

curl works on the server and cannot directly affect anything in the client's browser. It's the ideal method as it'll be your server talking to the payment gateway, not the client browser. The user cannot do ANYTHING to affect the server<->gateway communications, as that's literally occurring out of their reach.

Embedding any kind of pricing in client-side data structures is NEVER a good idea, unless it's for display-only purposes. You're leaving your profit margins completely in the hands of the user, and it won't take a genius to realize that they can reprice that $5000 flat screen tv to be negative $50 billion and get themselves one hell of a refund from you and a sweet tv thrown in as well.

Comment: Ok, but in API PDF they need POST data ... From the API (translated to english):

web server of merchant redirect customer to www.abc.com with parameters via POST...

Comment: curl can easily do ANY http verb, including post.

Comment: Yes, but I will get content of the page.. But I want to redirect user to that page..

Comment: if that api requires critical data like prices/quantities to be passed around via client-side operations, I'd suggest you seriously consider switching payment providers.

Comment: +1 for this, off-topic: care to share wich payment provider are you working with?